# Spring Filter along with custom filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, filter, sitemesh

I have following filter configured in web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.org.security.AccessFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
          <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

This is my custom filter, on which I check the requested page for the authorization:

```
    <filter>
         <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>com.zk.dcs.webapp.security.AccessFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Everything works fine, but does not render the UI properly.

Seeking support, what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you use spring security also, or just the custom filter? in browser debug what http response code do you get for the missings elements?

Comment: USING SPRING SECURITY ALSO, HERE IS MY SAMPLE CODE: if(isAuthorized(url,request)){
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }else{
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/common/forbidden.jsp").forward(request, response);
      
  }

Comment: IT SEEMS LIKE WHEN WE FORWARD IT IS NOT ABLE TO CHAIN THROUGH OTHER FILTERS, CORRECT ME IF i AM WRONG.

Comment: if(isAuthorized(url,request)){
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }else{
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/common/forbidden.jsp").forward(request, response);
      
  }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I identified the issue, my resources were being passed like ".css.html" format and I had filter on *.html
I fixed with some check like

```
if( (url.contains(".css")) || (url.contains(".js")) || (url.contains("img")) ||(url.contains("image"))){
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```